# Do you have savings, properties or other income, for example from stocks and shares?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

I am preparing to apply for standard visitor visa for a visit to the UK for 5 days for myself and my wife.

I am working in a Government Organization for last 8 years and my wife is a housewife and supported by me for all day to day costs. I have sufficient balance in my salary account to cover both of us during our trip.

**Question 1**

In the Employment & Income section one of the questions is Do you have savings, properties or other income, for example from stocks and shares?

Should I say 'yes'? If I say 'yes' it asks me the below question in tabular form

Total Monthly Income From   Amount in GBP(£)

It is asking for monthly income. Being a salaried employee, Provident Fund(PF) amount gets deducted from my monthly salary and I invest annually in Public Provident Fund and monthly in Mutual Funds.  How should I enter monthly income from these investments/savings?

**Question 2**

I have also booked refundable flight tickets and hotel with an option to pay at the hotel. Should I include these bookings in my VISA Application? I have read in other posts on TSE that it is not advisable to include flight/hotel bookings as it is against the guidance issued by UK Visas & Immigration.

Any help to answer these questions is much appreciated.

Comment: They want to know how much you liquidity you have, not how much you have invested.

Comment: In that case, the only liquidity that I have is the money in my salary account. How do I show the savings ? My intention is to show that a part of my monthly income is invested and saved and that I'm not spending my entire earning on a holiday trip.

Comment: @Nitin Bhargava Presumably your salary slip will show the at source deduction(s), and you can provide statements for your investments, so that UKVI can understand/reconcile your annual salary with your outgoings and see the surplus available for liquidity. If you get an annual investment income and the question only allows for monthly, divide the annual amount by 12 and explain the calculation in the application.

Answer (score 2):

Q1: not sure what the difficulty is? You enter the income that you receive from your investments (not the amount you invest). It’s not really any different from how you complete the information for your salaried income.
Q2: UKVI guidance states not to pre-book travel, and that you should not send flight/hotel bookings unless specifically requested. If you include them it will appear as if you’ve not read/understood the guidance, and they won’t be taken into account eg as evidence of your intention to leave (if that was the idea behind the question). https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf

Comment: The thing with these investments is that I don't receive any monthly income. I receive the interest annually (once in a year).

Comment: You can divide it by 12 and report an average per month